# Filter every character in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How do you force a Kendo grid to filter data after every character is typed, as in after every letter, not just when I press enter button?

I noticed that Kendo sends requests after every character typed, but without page size, and this request is used for autocomplete.  I want to change that to bind this data not to autocomplete, but to the main grid instead.

I am using built in filters, one for each column.

Comment: Hmm, do you want some textbox which will filter through grid as user is typing? In that case you will need some delay between request sends ... Or do you want it in column filter? I have prepare small [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe/18) like grid can be filtered when user types .. If you have (I assume you have) everything done on the server, you will need refresh grid after you set filter .. However by this way it is possible to do - I want to say there is not official solution from Telerik for this functionallity.

Comment: no I am using built in filters , each column has one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for later response, I didn't have much time. Anyway as I mentioned in comment, this functionallity is not supported by Telerik. So you have to create everything by yourself.

In following example I have used [filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit) event which is fired after you click on filter icon (and only once!). In that event I have modified filter elements to add custom classes and ids. Then in jQuery I am catching keyUp events and adding items into filter.

Here is small [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/orihu). I have implemented only equals filter, so you will have to do some modifications. But I hope it can help you in next work.